# Integral of $\sqrt{(1-\frac{a}{x^{a}})}$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to find the explicit integration for $\sqrt{(1-\frac{a}{x^{a}})}$ with respect to $x$. I am not sure what is the best substitution for the argument of the square root. Any suggestions?

We can assume that $a>0$ or even try some positive values for $a$.

Comment: what do you know about $a$?

Comment: Nothing. Lets assume it is something like 2/3 or, say, 3/4 etc

Comment: For generic $a$ a CAS gives $x H([-\frac{1}{2}, -\frac{1}{a}], [1 - \frac{1}{a}], a x^{-a})$, where $H$ is a hypergeometric function, so probably there is no closed-form solution. There is a simple closed-form solution for $a = 2 / 3$ but there appears to be no such solution for $a = 3 / 4$.

Comment: What is a CAS? And what is the general solution for a=2/3 then?

Comment: Then, there is no closed form solution, you have to use some special functions

Comment: The result in Mathematica does not use any hypergeometric functions by the way.

Comment: A computer algebra system (e.g., Maple, Mathematica, WA). WA gives (for $a = \frac{2}{3}$) http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%28sqrt%281+-+%282+%2F+3%29+%2F+%28x%5E%282+%2F+3%29%29%29%2C+x%29%3B

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I know, what I do not know is how to do this step by step. I mean, I can try all sorts of substitutions but I cannot find a simple one.

Comment: That's puzzling: WA (which I suppose uses the same integration code that Mathematica does) gives a result involving a hypergeometric function. What does Mathematica give? (And why not edit your question to include it?)

Comment: $\frac{a x \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{a};\frac{a-1}{a};a x^{-a}\right)-2
   x \sqrt{1-a x^{-a}}}{a-2}$ \\ Result from Mathematica

Comment: For generic $a$ indeed. I get the same. For $a=2/3$ I get a nice answer. I am interested in how to do this one step by step. How exactly do you suggest to change my question?

Comment: The second term looks like it did one partial integration step and then obtained hypergeometric series

Comment: This is weird. This is an integral that 1st year science students are supposed to solve, they most definitely know nothing about hypergeometric series. I am sure there is some trick (for some specific value of $a$ possibly) to get the result.

Answer (score 1):

With change of variable $t=a\;x^{-a}$ :

$$\int \sqrt{1-a\;x^{-a}}dx= -a^{1+\frac{1}{a}} \int (1-t)^{\frac{1}{2}}t^{-1-\frac{1}{a}}dt=-a^{1+\frac{1}{a}} B\left(x\:;\:-\frac{1}{a}\:,\: \frac{3}{2}\right)$$
$B(x;A,B)$ is the incomplete Beta function : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteBetaFunction.html

If you are especially intereseted in the case $a=\frac{2}{3}$ then $B\left(x\:;\:-\frac{3}{2}\:,\: \frac{3}{2}\right)=-\frac{2}{3}\left(\frac{1-x}{x}  \right)^{3/2}$

Comment: Hi and thanks. Again, although this seems reasonable I think this is not possible for 1st year science students (not even math students).

Comment: What exactly is the wording of the problem ? May be it is not asked to solve the integral. Depending how the question is written, may be one can answer without solving explicitly the integral.

Comment: It is to calculate the integral between 1 and 8. The actual problem is to calculate the arc length of the curve $y=x^{3/2}$ between $x=1$ and $x=8$.

Comment: $dy=\frac{3}{2}x^{1/2}dx\:\:$ then $\:\:ds=\sqrt{(dx)^2+(dy)^2}=\sqrt{1+\frac{9}{4}x}\:\:dx\:\:$. The integral is : $$\int_1^8 \sqrt{1+\frac{9}{4}x}\:\:dx\:\:$$ You see that providing additional context is useful.

Comment: I made a mistake. It is $y=x^{2/3}$ and not $y=x^{3/2}$. The first one is the one that confuses me yet.